# Finding a permutation $a$ such that $a^{-1}(12)(34)a=(56)(13)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, permutation-cycles

The question is to find the permutation $a $ such that $a^{-1}xa=y$ where $x=(12)(34) $ and $y=(56)(13)$

I found some answers to this question in this site but those don't clarify my doubt.

This is my doubt: $x=aya^{-1}$
$$x=(a(y))$$
$$(12)(34)=(a(5)  a(6))(a(1)  a(3))$$
So basically $a$ maps 5 to 1, 6 to 2, 1 to 3, 3 to 4.

Thus $$a: \begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&4&5&6\\
3&C&4&D&1&2
\end{pmatrix}$$

The possibilities for $C$ and $D$ are 5 and 6.

For any of those two cases for $C$ and $D$, I don't get the result which satisfies the given condition that $a^{-1}xa=y$

But if we take the inverse of this $a$ in the place of $a$ we get the result.  And all the other answers in this site says a as stated below and use $a^{-1}$ in the place of $a$.  I don't get the logic!! Can anyone check and tell me what I'm missing.  (Please don't mark this as duplicate. I've seen similar questions and the answers of none of them answer my question.)

Comment: I'll admit to not reading the entire question, but 9 times out of 10 with things like this people are just composing in the wrong order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- *"For any of those two cases for $C$ and $D$, I don't get the result which satisfies the given condition that $a^{-1}xa=y$"*

  Well, you should:

  - For $(C,D)=(5,6),$ $$a^{-1}xa=(152643)(12)(34)(134625)=(13)(56)=y.$$
  - For $(C,D)=(6,5),$ $$a^{-1}xa=(1543)(26)(12)(34)(1345)(26)=(13)(56)=y.$$
- *"But if we take the inverse of this $a$ in the place of $a$ we get the result."*

  No, we don't:

  - For $(C,D)=(5,6),$ $$axa^{-1}=(134625)(12)(34)(152643)=(35)(46)\ne y.$$
  - For $(C,D)=(6,5),$ $$axa^{-1}=(1345)(26)(12)(34)(1543)(26)=(36)(45)\ne y.$$
- Note that these are not the only possible choices for $a:$
  $$(12)(34)=(a(5)  a(6))(a(1)  a(3))$$
  will also be achieved if, for instance, $a$ maps $(5,6,1,3)$ to $(2,1,4,3),$ or to $(3,4,2,1).$

Comment: I don't get it. U have done it from right to left ?! Why do you do that?

Comment: [By definition, $ab$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Composition_of_permutations) (i.e. [$a\circ b$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition)) maps $k$ to $a(b(k)).$ See also Randall's comment above.

Comment: Ok so for the entire solution if we work from right to left, it works. I studies in "Topics  in  abstract algebra" by $I.N.Herstein$ and he operates from left to right so i got confused between those two!! Thanks for the help!!

Comment: LOL I can't believe I was right.